# How we can show Android Studio Vector Assets Android Version 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio

Vectors Assets Are not showing after update to 4.1.. Re Installing with "Export Setting & Not" both ways i used but still not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is the space in your window user name rename the user name space.

If you know the process that amazing but if dont know the process that how to rename the username you have to follow the step mention in this [link](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/change-account-name-windows-10/)

After that all your vector are now available and ready to use.

Enjoy :)